# Using set notation, define the set of even natural numbers between 100 and 500.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

> Using set notation, define the set of even natural numbers between 100 and 500.

This is what I have so far:

$P$ is even numbers so the set of natural numbers between 100 and 500 would be

$$P = \{x:x \in\mathbb  N, 100 < x < 500\}$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: if $N$ is the set of natural numbers, then your set includes all natural  numbers between 1 and 500.

Comment: Your set includes $101$, which is odd. Also note that there are many ways of describing the set.

Comment: So how would I write it? P = {x:x ∈ N, 100 ≤ x ≤ 500}

Comment: No. This description still includes 101. How would you characterise an even integer? (There are a few ways.)

Comment: Tbh I don't know how you would characterise an even interger.

Comment: $2 \mid n$ is one way ('two divides $n$').

Comment: @Harry: You say "I don't know how you would characterise an even interger", but you must have a concept of "even integer". What is this concept? For example, you might know that 14 is an even integer. How do you justify that believe? If you know how to express the argument that 6, 14 and 9002 are all even integers, then you know how to characterize it. The only thing left to do is replace that definition with set theoretical language. But go step by step.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, @Harry. If one of the answers below answers your question, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: @Harry: I would suggest $\{2x|x\in \mathbb N\wedge 200\le 2x\le500\}$.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For something very close to your proposal, you could say $$P=\{2x:x \in \Bbb N, 50 \lt x \lt 250\}$$  The $2x$ is one way to get rid of the odd numbers.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, this is exactly the solution i was looking for :)

Comment: @Harry: The protocol is that if you are happy with an answer that you accept it. There is no hurry, just letting you know ;-).

Comment: thank you all for the help :) trying to learn this atm and the guides ive been given haven't been much help

Comment: Good luck. Its a bit intimidating. My rule is generally ask forgiveness not permission...

Answer (score 36):

Here is one way:

$\begin{align}
P= \{ 
&102, 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 122, 124, 126, 128, 130, 132, 134, \\
&136, 138, 140, 142, 144, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 162, 164, 166, 168, \\
&170, 172, 174, 176, 178, 180, 182, 184, 186, 188, 190, 192, 194, 196, 198, 200, 202, \\
&204, 206, 208, 210, 212, 214, 216, 218, 220, 222, 224, 226, 228, 230, 232, 234, 236, \\
&238, 240, 242, 244, 246, 248, 250, 252, 254, 256, 258, 260, 262, 264, 266, 268, 270, \\
&272, 274, 276, 278, 280, 282, 284, 286, 288, 290, 292, 294, 296, 298, 300, 302, 304, \\
&306, 308, 310, 312, 314, 316, 318, 320, 322, 324, 326, 328, 330, 332, 334, 336, 338, \\
&340, 342, 344, 346, 348, 350, 352, 354, 356, 358, 360, 362, 364, 366, 368, 370, 372, \\
&374, 376, 378, 380, 382, 384, 386, 388, 390, 392, 394, 396, 398, 400, 402, 404, 406, \\
&408, 410, 412, 414, 416, 418, 420, 422, 424, 426, 428, 430, 432, 434, 436, 438, 440, \\
&442, 444, 446, 448, 450, 452, 454, 456, 458, 460, 462, 464, 466, 468, 470, 472, 474, \\
&476, 478, 480, 482, 484, 486, 488, 490, 492, 494, 496, 498 \}
\end{align}$.

Another slightly shorter way:

$P= \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | 100 < n < 500 \text{ and } \sin ( n {\pi \over 2} ) = 0 \}$.

Inspired by Charlotte's answer:

$P= (2 \mathbb{N}+\{100\}) \setminus (2 \mathbb{N}+\{498\})$.

*Et iterum* (Haskell's take on Ross' answer):

```
[2*x | x <- [51..249] ]
```

Comment: I did think of this but thought it was too simple lol

Comment: ... you're not wrong.

Comment: I like this${}{}{}$

Comment: Is the addition of sets a commonly accepted notation? What would $\{a,b\}+\{c,d\}$ result in?

Comment: @Dave: $\{a, b, c, d\}$?

Comment: @copper.hat: A mapping over the set (in this case an addition) shouldn't be written like this: $2\mathbb{N} + 100$?

Comment: @rubik That would be union, and that is not at all what is meant in the post.

Comment: @rubik: It is just shorthand, if $\square$ is some binary operation, then $A \square B = \{ a \square b | a \in A, b \in B \}$. Then $\{a,b\}+ \{c,d\} = \{a+c,a+d,b+c,b+d\}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @copper.hat: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: If you want to use set builder notation, I suggest the variation on this answer (where $\vee$ is "or")
$P=\{x\in \mathbb N:x= 102 \vee x = 104 \vee x = 106 \vee x = 108 \vee \ldots\}$

Comment: @Meelo: If I do, I will be arrested by the MathJax police...

Comment: Downvoted because the answer seems to be trolling the OP rather than trying honestly to tell him what he needs to know. It is all well and good to show there are multiple ways to slice this cake, but clearly he's trying to do it the _straightforward_ way yet failing, and that deserves an answer that addresses his initial misconception. (If his misconception had been "there is a single correct way to write this", this would be a great answer, but I don't see that being the case).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Your comment seems harsh when the intent was to help by providing some alternatives (one light hearted). If you follow the comment trail you will note that I have attempted to guide the OP before answering. (In addition, albeit you could obviously not be privy to this, I had a number of email exchanges with the OP clarifying and expressing the OP's intent in the OP's desired manner.) I don't care about the -2, but am dismayed by your perception.

Comment: @copper.hat: As far as I can see, _all_ the proposals here are "light-hearted", as you term it. I would call them "unnecessarily comples". If you have a different purpose with your answer than attempting to trick the OP into writing his set in a more obfuscated way than he needs to, you have failed to indicate what that purpose could possibly be. Feel free to be "dismayed" by having your trolling of the OP called out -- my sympathy is entirely on his side, not on yours.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Why would I want to 'trick the OP...'??? You are seeing darkness where there is none.

Comment: The first (i.e. enumerating) variant certainloy does not deserve a downvote, the one unnecessarily invoking the sine function probably does. On the other hand, anyone using setbuilder notation for the set of even numbers between 100 and 103 *would* deserve being punished. - Which raises the problem: Where is limit at which one *should* switch from enumerating to setbuilder?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: 42, of course :-).

Answer (score 15):

Let $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,...\}$. You want a set which includes the even members of $\mathbb N$ that lie between 100 and 500. Well, a member $n$ of $\mathbb N$ is even precisely when $n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.

So $\{n\in\mathbb N:(\exists k\in \mathbb N)(n=2k)\text{ and } 100<n<500\}$ works.

(use the weak inequality $\leq$ if you want to include 100 and 500 in the set).

Comment: What does the k stand for?

Comment: What I am saying in the parentheses is "$n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$."

Comment: Ahhh ok thank you for the help :)

Comment: This notation is more useful than the other expressions since it offers many advantages in proving something.

Answer (score 15):

I would tend to use one of;

$P = \{ n \in \mathbb{N}: 100 < n < 500, 2\mathop{|}n \}$

or

$P = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: \text{$n$ even}, 100 < n < 500 \}$

The latter I suppose is slightly less formal, but it would be perfectly normal to see it used in a lecture or talk, say, and it is probably the clearest possible when speaking or reading.

Note $m \mathop{|} n$ means that $m$ divides $n$, i.e. $n$ is an integer multiple of $m$.

Comment: I think it would be better to use $\&$, $\wedge$, or "and" instead of the commas.

Comment: Another similar alternative would be to use $n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ as the predicate.

Comment: I have always seen `|` used as an equivalent for `such that`, so at first this confused me.

Answer (score 5):

The most succinct way I know is
$$\{x|100\leq x \leq 500, x\in2\mathbb{Z}\}$$

Inspired by copper.hat and NicolajK, *inter alia*, here are some further valid answers:
$$\left\{2x+100\Bigg|\prod_{i=0}^{200}(x-i)=0\right\}$$
$$\{x|x\text{ is an even integer between 100 and 500}\}$$
$$\left\{x\Bigg|x=\frac{p^{(2n)}(0)}{p^{(2n-1)}(0)}, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\},\quad p(x)=\sum_{i=100}^{500}x^i$$
$$\{x|x=\log_2[G:H],\,H\subseteq G,\,|H|\leq 2^{100},\,|G|=2^{500}\},
\quad G\text{ is a group}$$
$$\begin{aligned}&\{((q\text{ incr})0)|\exists p\in\mathbb{H},
\\&q=
\\&\lambda pfx.((\lambda MNfx.N(Mf)x)(\lambda MNfx.(NM)fx)f(f(f(f(fx))))f(f(x)))f((pf)pfx)
\\&\text{and}
\\&\lambda M.\lambda N.(\lambda n.n(\lambda x.(\lambda ab.\lambda b))
(\lambda ab.a))(\lambda mn.n(\lambda nfx.n(\lambda gh.h(fg))(\lambda u.x)(\lambda u.u)\\& m) M N)q(\lambda MNfx.(NM)fx)f(f(f(f(fx))))f(f(f(x)))f((pf)pfx)\}\end{aligned}$$
where $\mathbb{H}=\{\lambda fx.x,\lambda fx.fx,\lambda fx.f(fx),\lambda fx.f(f(fx)),\dots\}$.

Comment: I like this. It has inspired me.

Comment: Me too, it looks like the first solution i had in my mind $\{x|100\leq x \leq 500, \frac{x}{2}\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: Nikolaj, with k. @kai: If you write the arithmetic operation $\tfrac{x}{2}$, you should maybe specify a sensible domain for $x$ to range over. $\mathbb Q$ will be the shortest answer.

Comment: I would +1 again if I could. Quidquid Latine dictum sit viditur altum. With apologies to Fr. Roderick, my latin teacher.

Comment: $\{x|\text{x, integer, non est a duobus divisibilis, et maior quam centum, et minus quam quingenti}\}$

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Computer scientists know that any binary number that is greater than zero is even, if the least significant bit is zero
$$ \{x:x \in \Bbb N, 100 \lt x \lt 500, x=(b_8\dots b_10)_2\} $$
Cryptographers might do it like this
$$ \{x:x \in \Bbb N, 100 \lt x \lt 500, x\equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 2)\} $$

Answer (score 3):

Some more versions:

1. $\{x\in 2\Bbb N|100<x<500\}$ or $\{x\in 2\Bbb Z|100<x<500\}$
2. $2\Bbb N \cap (100;500)$ or $2\Bbb Z\cap (100;500)$

Answer (score 2):

Using remainder classes, you can express it as
$$
P = \lbrace 100 + [n]_{400} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace
$$
Which is equal to
$$
P = 100+\mathbb{Z}_{400}
$$

Answer (score 2):

If we really want short, we could do this:

$$2\mathbb Z\cap[100,500]$$

If you need the set brackets:

$$\{x:x\in 2\mathbb Z\cap[100,500]\}$$

where $[a,b]=\{x:x\in \mathbb R \land a \le x \le b\}$, the normal sense of $[a,b]$

Answer (score 1):

A few more ways to express it:

$P=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:100<x<500\land\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor=\frac{x}{2}\}$

$P=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:100<x<500\land x\equiv0\mod{2}\}$

$P=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:100<x<500\land\frac{x}{2}\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Answer (score 1):

$\{|n| \mid n\in E, 100<|n|<500\}$

where

$E\equiv\{\emptyset\}\cup\{x\mid\exists (y\in E).\,x=\left(y\cup\{y\}\cup\{y\cup\{y\}\}\right)\}$

Comment: This is beautiful. So if there's a set $y$ of order $n-2$ in $E$, then $x$ has order $(n-2)+1+1 = n$. Can you prove, though, that there are no odd-ordered elements in the set?

Comment: @charlotte: No, you're right I was sloppy. To guarantee there are no extra sets in it, I need to add the condition that the $y$'s are also of the form $y'∪{y'}∪{y'∪{y'}}$ for some $y'$ in $E$. I mirrored the von Neumann construction of the countable set of ordinals - I can give you some more references on these constructions if you like.

Comment: Sure, but I won't be able to really get into it until my exams are done.

Comment: @charlotte: The solution is skipping every second number in the [von Neumann model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) of N. Given any finite set $X=\{a,b,\dots,s,t\}$ with cardinality $n$, the set $\mathrm{succ}(X):=X\cup\{X\}=\{a,b,\dots,s,t,X\}$ has cardinality $n+1$ (as no set in standard set theory contains itself, see [this axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)). So $\mathrm{succ}(\mathrm{succ}(Y))$, which is $Y\cup\{Y\}\cup\{Y\cup\{Y\}\}$, adds the cardinality by $2$. The set $E$ is generated by $\emptyset$ of size $0$.

Comment: @charlotte: I've discussed these concepts in my online notebook, see [successor set](http://axiomsofchoice.org/successor_set), followed by [first infinite von Neumann ordinal](http://axiomsofchoice.org/first_infinite_von_neumann_ordinal), followed by [natural number](http://axiomsofchoice.org/natural_number). I try to elaborate on the axioms in the entry [set theory](http://axiomsofchoice.org/set_theory) and I say something on models [here](http://axiomsofchoice.org/univalence_axiom) (skip right to the Motivation section).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that has not yet been suggested here:

$$P=\{n\in\mathbb{N}|[100<n<500]\wedge[(-1)^n=1]\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common way of listing a set of even numbers:

$P=\{2x + 100:x\in\mathbb{N}, 0\leq x\leq 200\}$

This just means:
Let P be the set of numbers yielded from "2x + 100" where x is a natural number and x is between 0 and 200 (inclusive).

If you start evaluating 2x + 100 with the numbers from 0 to 200, you get:

- 2(0) + 100 = 100
- 2(1) + 100 = 102
- ...
- 2(200) + 100 = 500

Comment: I don't think "$x\in[0\le x \le 200]$" is standard notation. What is "$x\in$" supposed to achieve here?

Comment: Oh, I see your point, I'm being redundant. Thanks, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \left\{ x \mid x \in \mathbb{N},\ 2 \mid x,\ 100 \leq x \leq 500 \right\} $$

Since you haven't specified, I'm assuming *between 100 and 500* is inclusive.

$2 \mid x$ means *$2$ is a divisor of $x$*, or alternatively, *$x$ is evenly divisible by $2$*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more longwinded approach to help clarify what's going on. But be explicit in how you define 'between'. In this sense, between could be interpreted as $100 \leq x \leq 500$ **or** $100 < x < 500$. As long as you are explicit about your assumption, you're fine.

The sentence "Define the set of even natural numbers between 100 and 500" can be broken into several components:

1. P = {even natural numbers between 100 and 500}
2. P = {elements of x in natural numbers such that (x is even) AND (x is greater than 100) AND (x is less than 500) }
3. P = $ \{ x \in \mathbb{N} : (\exists k \in \mathbb{N} \quad x = 2k) AND (x > 100) AND (x < 500) \} $
4. P = $ \{ x \in \mathbb{N} : (\exists k \in \mathbb{N} \quad x = 2k) \land [(x > 100) \land (x < 500)] \} $

This way makes the inequality $100 < x < 500$ explicit using the logical and operator.